# insert a custom uitableviewcell subview in a uiview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UIView that holds a UITableView, however the UITableView has a 30 pxl gap at the top in which i would like to add a static UITableViewCell programmatically.

I have tried to do this but I cannot seem to get it to appear, this is the code I am using I am not 100% sure if this is correct as its the first time trying it but to my knowledge it seems like it should be displaying.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

[selectAllCell setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 80.0)];
[selectAllCell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"all"];
[self.view insertSubview:selectAllCell aboveSubview:subModelTableView];

//.. other stuff
}
```

everything else in this view works perfectly.. so just wondering how I can get this uitableviewcell to display.

EDIT, I have updated the code in my viewDidLoad method but still I am not having any luck with this dran thing.

Comment: I've done exactly this with no issue. A UITableViewCell can be used outside of a tableView, and if you have a need to do it got for it! However, not so sure about "[selectAllCell sizeToFit];" - I usually set the frame of the cell, then use that as its dimension.

Comment: I do have a need.. just I am having troubles trying to achieve it.. dose my code look correct? because at the moment I cannot get anything but a toobar to appear...

Comment: Treat the cell like any other view, not a control (sizeToFit). Is it getting hidden under something else - set a UIView with a green background color as the backgroundView, and see what happens.

Comment: I have updated my code and its still messing me about, I have set the views background color to green but its still playing hide and seek with me.

Comment: I have tried about a zillion things.. im clearly missing something because i cannot get anything to appear above the self.view and im about to loose my cool... so frustrating..

Comment: Add logs or asserts to be 100% sure all the objects you are using in viewDidLoad are not nil.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a table view cell outside a table view?  Just slap a UIView with an embedded button over the empty area.  If that doesn't meet your needs for some reason, a fairly simple UIView or UIControl subclass should get the job done.

Comment: well I just wanted it to look like a static cell.. just thought that was the best way to get it looking like that.. okay I will try just a button (plain rectangle one)

Comment: For the plain table view style, it shouldn't be too hard to make the UIView look more or less like a cell in the table.  Of course, it won't scroll, but perhaps you don't want it to.

Comment: effectively I want the look of a cell but the response of a button.. so when its selected it just executes a method I have related to that click... thanks for the help im going to try out a button now. :)

Comment: I cannot get anything other than a UIToobBar to appear above the uitableview.. everything else, cell, button etc just do not display...

Comment: So just for fun, change the tableView frame to say 400,0,320,50. Can you see anything now? Change the static cell's frame to 100,0,320,100 - can you see it now? Dump the subviews? Something is seriously wrong if its in the subviews, nothing is over it, etc. Try to get one view working, then add another, then another. When all seems broken you have to backup far and start from something that works, then add to it. also, try adding the cell to the subviews so it float over everthing. Once you see it you can start playing with it. I often set background colors to see where views are.

Comment: okay cool.. been playing round with it but ill try what you have suggested and let you know how I get on.